# How to get selected elements from a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a form and a part of this form is a list which has five elements. These elements can be hovered by mouse. The hovered elements have class of `selected`. The question is how can I take the value of this elements in order to send it to server?

```
<ul id="service" class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
    <li id="1">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li id="4">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
    </li>
    <li id="5">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You seem to have accidentally your code, however this selector: `$('li.selected')` and the `map()` function should do what you need.

Comment: Now you've updated the question to contain the HTML, what value do you want to send? The `id` of the `li` elements?

Comment: document.getElementById("<your id>").value?

Comment: The code I had first was: <input type='hidden' id="1" value='1'/> for every li

Comment: I want to take the value of the selected li. I tried with javascript but I get undefinied @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That's my point, the `li` elements cannot have a value, so what are you trying to get?

Comment: Yes...you can manually set input type='hidden' inside a form element by checking li selected and in the end you call form submit manually too. If you want an example...tell me.

Comment: this what I had <li><input type='hidden' id="1" value='1'/><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></li>  . How to take the value of the selected fields when I submit the form @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct this is what you need:

```
$('#service li').on('hover', function() {
    sendToServer($(this).text());
});
```

And if you need to check selected class:

```
$('#service li').on('hover', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        sendToServer($this.text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo, if your `<li>` looks like this:

```
<li>
    <input type="hidden" id="3" value="3">
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o">c</i></li>
<li>
```

demo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#service li').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected'); // add selected class on hover
        var data = $(this).find(':hidden').val(); // get input hidden value inside the li
        sendToServer(data); // call send to server function passing data variable
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
});




function sendToServer(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // insert send to server program here
}
```

```css
.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="service" class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="1" value="1">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o">a</i></li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="2" value="2">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o">b</i></li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="3" value="3">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o">c</i></li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="4" value="4">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o">d</i></li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="5" value="5">
        <i class="fa fa-smile-o">e</i></li>

</ul>
```